# How to set BlackMagic-Decklink-LastFrameShown option (in video card settings) programmatically?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

We can enable/disable decklink-LastFrameShown option by  BlackmagicDesktopVideoUtility.exe ,But I need to change that programmatically.

I did not see anything about it in decklink SDK.

Please tell me where are saved BlackMagic-Decklink video card settings? (maybe in a file or registry but I can't find it)

OS = Windows 8.1  ,BlackmagicDesktopVideoUtility version=10.5

Thanks. (Sorry for my English)

UPDATE :

I found that Decklink-LastFrameShownvideo (and other video card settings) saved in registry :
HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DeckLink\Settings\1D482621\IdleVideoOutputOperation  Value= Black/LastFrame

But when I change it manually not affect.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Nicholas Gill (in [Blackmagic forum](http://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=41596)) :

> Hi Mitra,
>
> It is possible to set the 'last-frame-shown' (Idle Output) setting
>   from the DeckLink API.
>
> First query the BMDDeckLinkSupportsIdleOutput attribute 1 via the
>   IDeckLinkAttributes interface [2] to determine if the device supports
>   idle output.
>
> If supported, set the bmdDeckLinkConfigVideoOutputIdleOperation [3]
>   configuration item via IDeckLinkConfiguration [4] to the desired idle
>   setting - BMDIdleVideoOutputOperation [5].
>
> Please note the comment in [4], WriteConfigurationToPreferences must
>   be called if the application wants to save the configuration changes,
>   otherwise any changes made will be reverted when the
>   IDeckLinkConfiguration object is released.
>
> Cheers,
>
> -nick
>
> [1](http://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=41596) 2.7.17 DeckLink Attribute ID [2] 2.5.17 IDeckLinkAttributes
>   Interface [3] 2.7.18 DeckLink Configuration ID [4] 2.5.15
>   IDeckLinkConfiguration Interface [5] 2.7.41 Idle Video Output
>   Operation BMDIdleVideoOutputOperation enumerates the possible output
>   modes when idle. bmdIdleVideoOutputBlack When not playing video, the
>   device will output black frames. bmdIdleVideoOutputLastFrame When not
>   playing video, the device will output the last frame played.